# MySQL Search PHP Script

Tags: php, mysql, search

I would like to create a script to search a MySQL table (data). The table has two columns (ID & PRICE). Search must be done by ID and Price has to be displayed in the page, any ideas?

Comment: You have to at least try something.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We like to help with actual, concrete problems. We will not do your homework for you. As of now, your question is a better fit for a freelancing site. Please try to solve this on your own, and as soon as you face an actual, programming related problem, ask your question.

Comment: Is this your first PHP+MySQL project?

Answer (score 2):

The query will be

```
select price from table_name where id = your_id
```

Comment: Most simplest and effective answer I have ever saw :-)